# Python - return first value for each key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, return

Can someone help possibly point out a way of retrieving the first value for each key in a defaultdict/dictionary?

For example I have this less than elegant solution:

```
d = {'4089e04a': ['24.0', '24.0', '24.0', '23.93', '23.93
', '23.93'], '408b2e00': ['20.91', '33.33'], '408b2e0c': ['44.44']}

print d.values()[0][0]
print d.values()[1][0]
print d.values()[2][0]
```

It does work - but is there a better way so that I'm not limited to only returning 3 values?   I can't work out how to get it working within specifying each key individually...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> d = {'4089e04a': ['24.0', '24.0', '24.0', '23.93', '23.93',\
'23.93'], '408b2e00': ['20.91', '33.33'], '408b2e0c': ['44.44']}
>>> [item[0] for item in d.values()]
['24.0', '20.91', '44.44']
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Dang - I knew it would be stupidly easy...need more coffee. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`d.values()` returns a `list`(py 2x) or `views`(py3x), you can iterate over it's each item and simply print `item[0]`

```
In [165]: d = {'4089e04a': ['24.0', '24.0', '24.0', '23.93', '23.93', '23.93'], '408b2e00': ['20.91', '33.33'], '408b2e0c': ['44.44']}

In [167]: for item in d.values():
   .....:     print item[0]
   .....:     
24.0
20.91
44.44
```

Comment: @Sheng you must be using py3x then.